# Unexpected behaviour of the "mv" command as non-root user

Tags: linux, security, mv

Recently, I've stumbeld upon this:

My non-root user `myuser` tried to move a file, that belonged to `root` .. and it **worked**?!?

```
$ whoami
myuser

$ ls -lAhd
drwx------ 2 myuser myuser 4,0K  4. Nov 14:24 .

$ ls -lAh
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0  4. Nov 14:24 testfile.txt

$ mv testfile.txt testfile.txt.bak

$ ls -lAh
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0  4. Nov 14:24 testfile.txt.bak
```

So my question is:
Why does this work?

The "mv"-command should have been nagging at me for **not being root**, right?

I do understand, that:

- The file could be read by `myuser` (644 permissions, so file is readable by everyone)
- The file could be copied by `myuser` (because the directory belongs to `myuser`)

.. if this is, what's actually happening (I haven't had a look at the source-code of mv).

But `myuser` doesn't have write-privileges on the file.
So how could it possibly have deleted the original file?

Even if this is not, what's happening and the file is actually just "renamed", then that shouldn't have worked, neither, right?!?

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are not modifying the file, you are modifying the directory where the file resides (and where you have write permissions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have write permissions on the (source and target) directory, which is necessary for the rename system call to work. A more secure directory would not grant you write access.

Bad analogy: librarians do not need to open a book to catalog it on a different shelf.

Renaming is not quite the same as copying. Without read on the file, you cannot cp or use an editor. But you can rename it, on the same file system at least.

Comment: And (on modern systems) the "sticky bit" (`+t`) is there to prevent users other than the file owner from deleting files. You'll see it used in e.g. `/tmp`, which probably show as `drwxrwxrwt` in `ls -l`. See the "Restricted deletion flag or sticky bit" section in the [GNU manpage for chmod](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/coreutils/chmod.1.en.html)